# How to write SQLite query based on opposing values in two different tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm writing an auction system and can't figure out a query that will pull out the data for the items that a certain user has bid on but lost.

I tried subqueries and joins, but despite a lot of reading I don't understand them well, and certainly not how to apply them to my problem properly. I get either errors or the wrong data back.

### bids table:

```
itemID  user    bidAmount
------ -------  ---------
  1    spanky    11
  1    mister    13
  1    spanky    17

  2    spanky    10
  2    polgar    20
  2    spanky    25
  2    polgar    30

  3    polgar    20
  3    mister    25

  4    spanky    30
  4    mister    45
  4    spanky    50
  4    polgar    60
```

### items table:

```
itemID   highBidder itemName
------   ---------- --------
   1      spanky     hat
   2      polgar     tie
   3      mister     pot
   4      polgar     bed
```

For convenience if anyone wants to create these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE bids (itemID INT, user TEXT, bidAmount INT);
CREATE TABLE items (itemID INT, highBidder TEXT, itemName TEXT);
INSERT INTO bids (itemID,user,bidAmount) VALUES (1,'spanky',11), (1,'mister',13), (1,'spanky',17), (2,'spanky',10), (2,'polgar',20), (2,'spanky',25), (2,'polgar',30), (3,'polgar',20), (3,'mister',25), (4,'spanky',30), (4,'mister',45), (4,'spanky',50), (4,'mister',60);
INSERT INTO items (itemID,highBidder,itemName) VALUES (1,'spanky','hat'), (2,'polgar','tie'), (3,'mister','pot'), (4,'polgar','bed');
```

### Pseudocode:

```
SELECT (itemID, highBidder, itemName) 
FROM items 
WHERE highBidder !='spanky' 
AND [[include only distinct itemID from "bids" table where user='spanky']]
```

Should return data for itemID's 2 and 4 (not #1, because the user won that item, and not #3, because he never bid on that item.

Comment: I think you had it: `SELECT itemID, highBidder, itemName FROM items WHERE highBidder <> 'spanky' AND itemID in (select distinct itemID from bids where user='spanky')`

Comment: That's it, I had used the = sign instead of the word "in".  I'd spent hours on that for such a couple of errant characters...  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the `itemid`s that `'spanky'` has lost you can `group by itemid` the table `bids` and put the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select itemid
from bids
group by itemid
having max(bidamount) > max(case when user = 'spanky' then bidamount end)
```

So use this query to select the `itemid`s from the table `items`:

```
select * from items
where itemid in (
  select itemid
  from bids
  group by itemid
  having max(bidamount) > max(case when user = 'spanky' then bidamount end)
)
```

This way you only use the user's name only once.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kvHYJ75jrPKe2zBBZ5CGNc/0).
Results:

```
| itemID | highBidder | itemName |
| ------ | ---------- | -------- |
| 2      | polgar     | tie      |
| 4      | polgar     | bed      |
```

Comment: . . I missed that your first answer is the same as my answer.

Comment: No worries (it happened to me also usually after hours...)